# asp.net web forms URL routing doesn't map to the physical file

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing, global-asax

I have an asp.net web form website in which i use URL routing
the thing is when ever I try ti navigate to a matched route e.g "http://localhost:51878/brand/adidas" it doesn't open the specified aspx file it shows HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found and navigates to D:\Websites\Website\brand\adidas

update: I tried adding break points to the global.asax.cs file apparently it doesn't even go through the Application_Start function

here's my
global.asax`

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" %>
```

and here's my global.asax.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


    public partial class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("brandsRoute", "brand/{brand}", "~/brand.aspx");
        }

    }
```

would u please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine, except for the erroneous > character under your `using` statements, which may be causing your code not to build, and perhaps you are running a last good build version that doesn't include your new route.